# "This app has no process types yet" although everything has been deployed

Tags: heroku, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to host my discord bot on Heroku, and it doesn't show dynos even though It has deployed successfully. And I have already tried refreshing for 5 minutes in recourses. So I thought maybe something is wrong with ProcFile

```
heroku ps:scale worker=1
worker: python main.py
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file name isn't ProcFile, but Procfile, try this.

Answer (score 0):

The Procfile only requires one line, which is: `worker: python {programName}.py`. So if your main file is named `bot.py`, your Procfile would be:

```
worker: python bot.py
```

In your case, I supposed that your main file is named `main.py`. Then, your Procfile should be exactly written like this:

```
worker: python main.py
```

So in other words, the line `heroku ps:scale worker=1` isn't required or even supposed to be in the Procfile.